# How to port forward to a different ip-address on the same network interface?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have 3 systems spread accross 2 networks:

- computer 1 with 1 NIC: with ip-address 192.168.10.22
- computer 2 with 1 NIC: with ip-address 192.168.10.30 and 192.168.11.30
- computer 3 with 1 NIC: with ip-address 192.168.11.33

I want a reverse SSH-tunnel from computer 3 to computer 1.
Computer2 to computer3 shall use port 2222, whereas computer1 to computer 2 should use port 22.
In my case for some reason it doesn't work. Hereunder what I tried:

On computer2:

```
$sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# External machine connects to 192.168.11.30:22, forwarded to 192.168.10.30:2222
$sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.11.30 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.30:2222
$sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.10.30 --dport 2222 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.11.30

# Internal machine2 connects to 192.168.10.22:2222, forwarded to 192.168.11.30:22
$sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.10.30 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.30:22
$sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.11.30 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.10.30
```

#Initiate reverse SSH:

```
   $ssh -N -R 2222:192.168.10.30:22 user@192.168.10.22
   Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 2222
```

On computer3:

```
   $ssh user@192.168.11.30
   ssh connect to host 192.168.11.30 port 22: Connection refused.
```

Why am I having the warning and how can I fix the fact that I cannot connect?